# Testing if an object has been serialized with MsgPack in Python

Tags: python, serialization, msgpack

Is there a way dynamically test an object (message) to determine if it has been serialized via MsgPack in python?

Answer (score 1):

No: there is no [magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) or version number out of the box.

As [stated by msgpack's author](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/issues/148#issuecomment-23962383) you have to do it on your side if needed:

> MessagePack itself doesn't provide versioning in the format because applications need to build a protocol or file format that includes version description on top of it if they need to be self-describing about its format strictly.